# Use GitHub created VPS for a long time

Tags: windows, github, github-actions, vps, github-for-windows

I have created a Windows VPS using GitHub and ngrok. It works good for some time but after 30 minutes it automatically shuts down. Here is my GitHub repository link:

https://github.com/arqamiy2k2/testproject

Can any one tell me how this VPS server can be online for a long period of time?

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to create a VPS out of GitHub Actions.  GitHub Actions is a system designed to perform CI and other repository-based actions.  It's not designed to be a VPS, and that's not really an appropriate use of those resources.

There isn't a way to keep those VMs online for a long time because they're explicitly intended to be ephemeral.  If you need a real VPS, then you'll need to purchase a real VPS.